Error of 'P404 Migration skipped. Already completed.' on error_log file
Error_log files of two websites, https://saahm.net/error_log and https://ochim.com/error_log have the very frequent repetitive errors (P404 Migration skipped. Already completed.) like every second, which makes like those files 750 kB bigger a day. Would you please have a look at it and let me know your opinion?
TIA.

Same problem here.I may have identified the cause of the error. Are you using the "All 404 Redirect to Homepage" plugin ?

Good spot. As a temporary fix you can remove the error_log() from the plugin's functions.php, or just remove the add_action('plugins_loaded', 'p404_migrate_options'); altogether, and report this to the authors to get fixed.

Already reported here: "No, there is no issue as this is a test we conducted, and will disappeared in the next update."

You could reply to that and say yes, it is an issue - it's filling up my logs.

Yes, both websites are using All 404 Redirect to Homepage plugin. I disabled the plugin and deleted the error_log file. Now I don't have the problem anymore.
